# Продолжительность песни/видео discord.py

Tags: ffmpeg, discord.py

Как получать длительность аудио файла используя discord.py с ffmpeg? Тем самым запрещая воспроизводить что-либо длиной больше чем 10 минут

Answer (score 1):

Ну, тут 2 варианта.
Если ты работаешь только с ютубом, то просто получаем длину трека от ютуба.
Я делаю это так.

```
ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({'outtmpl': '%(id)s%(ext)s'})
#global video
with ydl:
    result = ydl.extract_info(
        str("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8S9D6cZlrg"),
        download=False # We just want to extract the info
    )
    if 'entries' in result:
        # Can be a playlist or a list of videos
        video = result['entries'][0]
    else:
        # Just a video
        video = result

print("Видео идёт - ",video['duration'])
```

Естественно это youtube_dl
И есть вариант просто узнать длину файла через ffmpeg, на для этого его нужно скачать, и по мне не то что вам нужно.